# Repeated std::move on an boost::asio socket object in C++11

Tags: boost, c++11, boost-asio, move, move-semantics

I am exploring using boost::asio along with C++11 features. In particular, I am focusing on an example called "async_tcp_echo_server.cpp", located here (code is also shown at the end of my question):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

My question involves the `tcp::socket` member `socket_` of the `server` class. In the `do_accept()` method of the `server` class, `socket_` is passed to `async_accept()`. (According to the asio documentation, `async_accept()` requires, as its first parameter, the `socket` to accept the connection into.) So far, so good.

The next parameter, the callback for the asynchronous accept operation, is a lambda function. The body of the lambda constructs a new `session` object, whose constructor also needs the same `socket`. Interestingly, `socket` objects cannot be copied; so in the example, the `socket_` object, which is a member of the `server` object, is passed using `std::move()`.

I understand that the "one and only" `socket_` object (which is a "permanent" member of the `server` object) is "moved" into the `session` object. Fine -- `socket` object is not copied, but moved -- everybody's happy.

But what happens on the next call to `async_accept()`? Is the same `socket_` (member of `server`), that was previously moved, passed in again? When we "move" a member, what is left behind? Is there a magical fountain of unlimited `socket` objects?

Or is something really less-than-obvious happening here? When the `socket` is moved into the `session`, is the contents of the "left behind/moved from" object (`socket_` member of `server`) *swapped* with the contents of the "new" `session` object's own "not-yet-constructed" `socket_` member? Am I even making sense?

## Summary

Code is below. Program flow is fairly simple. `main()` constructs a single `server` object. The `server` makes repeated calls to `async_accept()`. Each `async_accept()` callback creates a new `session` object, each constructed with a (fresh?) `socket`. Where do all the "fresh" `socket` objects come from, if they are simply (repeatedly) "moved" from the same `socket_` member in the (single) `server`?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
: public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session( tcp::socket socket )
    : socket_( std::move( socket ) )
    {}

    void start() {
        do_read();
    }

private:
    void do_read() {
        auto self( shared_from_this() );
        socket_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer( data_, max_length ),
            [this, self]( boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length )
            {
                if( !ec ) {
                    do_write( length );
                }
            }
        );
    }

    void do_write( std::size_t length ) {
        auto self( shared_from_this() );
        boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer( data_, length ),
            [this, self]( boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/ )
            {
                if( !ec ) {
                    do_read();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};


class server {
public:
    server( boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port )
    : acceptor_( io_service, tcp::endpoint( tcp::v4(), port ) )
    , socket_( io_service )
    {
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            socket_,
            [this]( boost::system::error_code ec )
            {
               if( !ec ) {
                   std::make_shared<session>( std::move( socket_ ) )->start();  // is this a *swap* of socket_ ???
               }

               do_accept();
            }
        );
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
};


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    try {
        if( argc != 2 ) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        server s( io_service, std::atoi( argv[1] ) );

        io_service.run();

    } catch( std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move semantics can be thought of as passing ownership of resources. Resource Acquisition Is Instantiation (RAII) is the concept of assigning ownership of resources at the time of object construction and the releasing of those resources at destruction. Move semantics allow for the transfer of ownership of resources at other times besides construction and destruction.

In this case, the object (`server::socket_`) is the recipient of a transfer of ownership of the OS socket resource from `server::acceptor_`. That transfer occurs at some point after `async_accept()` returns, when a client connects. The newly connected socket resources are moved into `socket_`, and the callback lambda function is called. During the lambda, the socket resources are moved into `session::socket_`. Server::socket_ only owned the resource for a fraction of a microsecond.

Move semantics allow RAII classes to exist in the twilight state of not owning any resources. Think of a `unique_ptr` after a call to release (it refers to no memory). The server::socket_ after the move out still has space to hold a resource, but for the moment it owns nothing.

The last thing the lambda function does is call `do_accept`, which calls `async_accept()` again. A reference to `socket_` is passed in. When another client connects at some point in the future, `async_accept()` will transfer ownership of a newly connected OS socket there.

Comment: Thanks for detailing the process! Sorry I didn't notice your answer a long time ago.

Answer (score 21):

As documented in [`tcp::socket` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload5.html):

> Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if
>   constructed using the basic_stream_socket(io_service&) constructor.

The above means that you can `move` the original `socket` object from `server` to `session` as many times as you need.

Comment: One more thought... is this not rather obfuscated code? Does this not expose hidden functionality that should be more explicit?

Comment: @Kevin H. Patterson Where is a hidden functionality here? The code looks to me rather intuitive. The alternative would be (like in non c++11 examples) to expose `session::socket_`, which is kindof implementation detail...

Comment: @Igor R. Well, my understanding is, using move semantics, the (source) rvalue should be left in a state ready for destruction. The less-than-obvious thing here (to me) is that the rvalue would be re-initialized as if it were a freshly constructed object after we've moved it. Certainly the code is clean, but knowing this outcome is (imho) an implementation detail of the `session` constructor, is it not? Otherwise, I don't think we should normally attempt to use (or re-use) an rvalue after it has been moved somewhere else, right?

Comment: @Kevin H. Patterson The *result* of `move` is an rvlaue (or so called xvalue) and it's "in a state ready for destruction". The moved-from object `socket_` is an lvalue!

Comment: @KevinH.Patterson The bottom of this page: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_04.html suggests to me that the source of a move should be left in a state that is destructible but has released side-effect resources, which is exactly what's happening here.