# boost::asio::async_read 100% CPU usage on simple example

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost, boost-asio

In boost::asio [standard](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp) after `async_accept()` the `socket` object is moving to the `session` object (which handles all `async_read()` calls) by initializing it as following:

```
std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
```

And when constructing a `session` it's moving again (isn't it reduntantly?):

```
session(tcp::socket socket)
  : socket_(std::move(socket))
```

Then reading from a client is done as following:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, ...
```

And all goes well. But when I trying to make `async_read()` not from the `session` object but directly from the `async_accept()` and use it's `socket` object, CPU is raising to 100% immediately after client connects. Why?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Server
{
public:
  Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
         const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)    
    : acceptor_(io_service, endpoint),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
       [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
       {
         if (!ec) {
           char* buf = new char[5];
           boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
              boost::asio::buffer(buf, 5),
              [this, buf](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
              {
                if (!ec) {
                  std::cout.write(buf, 5);
                  std::cout << std::endl;
                }
                delete[] buf;
              });
         }
         do_accept();
       });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int port = 22222;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), port);
  new Server(io_service, endpoint);
  io_service.run();
}
```

Boost 1.49

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers! I ended up by moving `socket_` before using it:

```
tcp::socket *socket = new tcp::socket(std::move(socket_));
```

Also the same problem is discussed at [Repeated std::move on an boost::asio socket object in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715794/repeated-stdmove-on-an-boostasio-socket-object-in-c11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *peer* socket passed to [`basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html) is not open, then it will be opened during the `async_accept()` operation.  Otherwise, if the *peer* is already open, then *handler* will be posted into the `io_service` for invocation with an error code of `boost::asio::error::already_open`.  Hence, the posted code causes a tight asynchronous call chain to form:

1. The `async_accept()` operation is invoked the first time, causing `socket_` to be opened.
2. The `async_accept()` handler invokes `do_accept()`, initiating an `async_accept()` operation.
3. `socket_` is already open, causing the `async_accept()` operation to post its handler into the `io_service` with an error of `boost::asio::error::already_open`.
4. The asynchronous call chain starts back at step 2.

This behavior is not observed in the official examples because the [socket's move operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/operator_eq_/overload1.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_stream_socket.operator_eq_.overload1.remarks) causes the the moved-from object to be in the same state as if it was constructed using [`basic_stream_socket(io_service&)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload1.html) constructor.  Thus, the moved-from object is in a closed state, and ready for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the single `socket_` in all places, so when a connection is accepted, your handler calls do_accept() again which is using the same `socket_`, then it's accepted again and again...

You probably need to always use a new socket like below:

```
  void do_accept()
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> psocket(new tcp::socket(io_service));
    acceptor_.async_accept(*psocket, boost::bind(&Server::handleAccept, this, psocket, _1));
  }

  void handleAccept(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> psocket, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (!ec) {
    char* buf = new char[5];
    boost::asio::async_read(
      *psocket,
      boost::asio::buffer(buf, 5),
      [this, buf](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
      {
        if (!ec) {
          std::cout.write(buf, 5);
          std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        delete[] buf;
      });
    }
    do_accept();
  }
```