# Boost websocket_server_async.cpp example

Tags: boost-asio, boost-beast

I was reading the boost [websocket example here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp).
In the listener class, it initializes the socket_ object. After listener accepted the connection, the socket_ is being **std::move** to the session object. I didn't see any logic to recreate the socket_ object. When the listener accept another connection, would it be an issue?

Comment: Have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715794/repeated-stdmove-on-an-boostasio-socket-object-in-c11). See Igor R's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only question you need to ask is: Is the state of a `socket_` invalid after moving it to a session? The answer is no.

After moving a socket object, it basically is reset to its original state, as if newly constructed.