# C++ move constructors without rvalue references?

Tags: c++, boost, move-semantics

I just found some code in Boost paraphrased as the following:

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
  B(A a): a_(std::move(a)) {}
private:
  A a_;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b(std::move(a));
}
```

Assuming this works, why use move constructor/assignment with an rvalue reference?  Or does a move constructor/assignment just save you the trouble of a second `std::move()` call?

Comment: Because the *actual* Boost.Move code is not your "paraphrased" version.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "why use move constructor/assignment with an rvalue reference". There is no move constructor and no assignment here (and no rvalue reference variable either).

Comment: `move constructor/assignment` are for the class itself, not it's parameters.  This is a quick way to take any type of `A` and get a copy+move or move+move.  The performance isn't the best, but you only have to write a single line of code to get OK performance.

Comment: If you tried to do this with an actual constructor, you would have a circular logic problem where you define the construct in terms of itself.

Comment: I think OP ask why having `B(A a): a_(std::move(a)) {}` instead of `B(A&& a): a_(std::move(a)) {}`.

Comment: Are you calling `B(A a)` a move constructor? Or are you saying that since `B(A a)`, move constructors/assignments should work with non-reference paramters too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++ move constructors without rvalue references?

`B(A)` is not a move constructor. It is a converting constructor.

> Assuming this works

This converting constructor does work.

> why use move constructor/assignment with an rvalue reference?

Because you cannot have a move constructor/assignment without an rvalue reference.

In case you meant to ask, why use rvalue reference converting constructor: It can avoid one move construction. The downside of that is needing an additional overload for lvalue references in case you want to be able to copy from those.

Comment: True, `B(A`) is a "converting constructor" (i.e. implicit conversion).  What if it were `explicit B(A)`?

Comment: @CyberMarine Then it's just a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

My "paraphrased" code actually comes from the code referenced by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17715794/558513) question so my question had already been asked and answered.