# std::move on boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio, move, move-semantics, asio

I'm reading the book *Functional programming in C++* and the source code of Chapter 12.

https://gitlab.com/manning-fpcpp-book/code-examples/-/blob/master/chapter-12/bookmark-service/service.cpp#L19

In this line, `std::move` is applied on `m_socket`.

After the construction of the first session object where `m_socket` is moved, `m_socket` is still used to construct the following session objects.

Is `m_socket` still effective after the move operation?

Comment: Look at Igor R.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715794/repeated-stdmove-on-an-boostasio-socket-object-in-c11)

Answer (score 0):

Even after 'stealing' the object to avoid unnecessary copying, it's leaving the object in a valid state. So it depends on how is that variable is used afterwards.